# Is the Bluetooth logo available as a character on iPhone?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Is there a font on iOS where there's a glyph for the Bluetooth logo? Some Dingbats, maybe, or Emoji? How about the WiFi logo?

EDIT: how about a third party font where there's such a character, the one that I could license and ship?

Comment: Several iPhone Unicode apps allow you to browse and search all glyphs, including the Private Use Area which contains several hundred emoji etc. But no Bluetooth or WiFi there, alas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the Bluetooth logo is not a glyph or a font-face character.

Comment: Technically speaking, it's a ligature of two characters from the Younger Futhark alphabet, AKA Norse runes - ᚼ and ᛒ. Futhark runes themselves are in the Unicode, but not the ligatures.

Comment: Well, ligature and logo are 2 different things. If you can programmatically join 2 characters into the bluetooth logo then thats great. And it seems like you answered your own question.

Comment: Is there a policy against logos in the Unicode? Apple logo, for example, is a private-use character U+F8FF. Windows logo is a private-use character in the Wingdings font.

Comment: There is no policy that I can think of or have come across.

Answer (score 5):

Like Seva said, It's a combination of runic Hagall (ᚼ) and Bjarkan (ᛒ). I was trying to do the same thing by combining the two symbols.

I accomplished this by first finding a font that had these two characters. I ended up using LeedsUni. You can download it here: http://www.personal.leeds.ac.uk/~ecl6tam/.

You'll need to reference the path where the font is located in info.plist.

```
  <key>UIAppFonts</key>
  <array>
    <string>Fonts/LeedsUni10-12-13.ttf</string>
  </array>
```

I then created two `UIView` objects(`UIButton` objects in my case) which overlapped each other so that the two characters lined up properly. Depending on the font you use, you may need to adjust x and y values for the UIView frames.

My code is in C# because I'm using Xamarin, but you should be able to do the same thing in Objective C or Swift.

```
UIView bleView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 34.0f, 34.0f));

string fontName = "LeedsUni";

UIButton bluetoothToSerialButton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
bluetoothToSerialButton.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 34.0f, 34.0f);
bluetoothToSerialButton.SetTitleColor(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().TintColor, UIControlState.Normal);
bluetoothToSerialButton.SetTitle("ᛒ", UIControlState.Normal);
bluetoothToSerialButton.Font = UIFont.FromName(fontName, 34.0f);

UIButton bluetoothToSerialButton2 = new UIButton(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
bluetoothToSerialButton2.Frame = new CGRect(-3.5f, 0, 34.0f, 34.0f);
bluetoothToSerialButton2.SetTitleColor(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().TintColor, UIControlState.Normal);
bluetoothToSerialButton2.SetTitle("ᚼ", UIControlState.Normal);
bluetoothToSerialButton2.Font = UIFont.FromName(fontName, 34.0f);

bleView.AddSubviews(new UIView[] { bluetoothToSerialButton, bluetoothToSerialButton2 });
```

Answer (score 4):

**Using Quartz2D in Swift 4.1**

If you hate using external fonts or adding a bunch of .png files, you may prefer a simple class to get the same effect using Quartz2D.

This works for me with a logo of 20x20 points.  You may want to optimize the geometry or line width.  Also note that the frame's width should be equal the height.

Note that you will need to use setNeedsDisplay if the size changes.

[image]

```
import UIKit
class BluetoothLogo: UIView {
    var color: UIColor!
    convenience init(withColor color: UIColor, andFrame frame: CGRect) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.color = color
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let h = self.frame.height
        let y1 = h * 0.05
        let y2 = h * 0.25
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: y2, y: y2))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: h - y2, y: h - y2))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: h/2, y: h - y1))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: h/2, y: y1))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: h - y2, y: y2))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: y2, y: h - y2))
        context?.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
        context?.setLineCap(.round)
        context?.setLineWidth(2)
        context?.strokePath()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

These are the icons from google material design you can download them from here https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=bluetooth&style=baseline
[image]

Comment: Here is the updated link: https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%3Abluetooth%3A

Answer (score 1):

No emoji, just checked on my iPad.

Just use a PDF or EPS of the bluetooth logo if you wan't it scalable, or just use a png otherwise.